# I received 9 downvotes in one minute? What happened?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

Take a look at my reputation. I received 9 downvotes in just a matter of a minute or two.

Do you think it is the right behavior for any member?

[image]

Comment: There is some advice on what to do in this thread http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/273494

Comment: Why should we take a look at your reputation? It is 1. Your account has also been suspended for the second time in a couple weeks, this time for a month. And if it matters, I didn't do any of those downvotes. Apparently you have antagonized someone else. I did downvote this question, mostly because of your behavior on this site.

Comment: @NES If you are down voting or up voting posts based on who wrote them and not based on their content, you are part of the problem. Past suspensions shouldn't be held against folks if they are currently playing by the rules. I understand that you have some probably justified bad feelings, but if you can't be objective you should not be interacting with his posts. Let it go. It's better for the site, and it's probably better for you.

Comment: In this case @ColleenV *who wrote them* largely equates with *their **poor** content*. What about this question deserves an upvote?

Comment: @NES sigh. You've missed my point entirely and you probably should review what "objective" means. Would you take the time to comment on and/or down vote this if it hadn't been written by a particular person? No? Then your behavior is partly to blame for the "broken" voting system that you complain about. [Be Nice](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), and if you can't be nice, don't hit the submit button. Vote based on the post, not the person, and if you can't see past the person, don't vote at all and let the rest of the community handle it.

Comment: worth noting that 'serial' upvoting/selecting an answer is *allowed*. I might have done this on weekends when I have good time to read and act.

Comment: Serial upvoting is against the rules, and if caught will be reversed just like serial downvoting.

Comment: Any of the stackexchange site is no place for bias. That looks like a work of a troll. Don't know who S/he is! @_@

Comment: @Maulik serial upvoting is explicitly banned. Maybe you meant something else by "upvoting/accepting"?

Comment: @NES: Nobody is saying you should upvote this post, or that you *shouldn't downvote* it at all. But surely you can see why people take exception to the fact that you admit to having downvoted *mostly* because you're not happy with OP's behavior on this site. ColleenV is absolutely right to point out that this sort of "tit-for-tat" behaviour is precisely what we *don't* want - from you, the OP here, or any of these (mostly mythical) trolls. If you wanna fight, go find a playground somewhere else.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. - Serial upvoting means voting up several answers written by one particular user. I believe Maulik was referring to looking at several answers on a leisurely afternoon, and upvoting the very good and deserving ones (not just those authored by one person). Grammatically, we could call that _serial upvoting_, too, but not in the same sense that SE normally uses that expression.

Comment: @snailboat FYI:  [Lost 5 questions following a serial downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269392/178179)

Comment: Yes, you got it! @J.R. *For me*, it is serial upvoting. And, this upvoting include questions, answers from various authors. But then, to bots, it might look suspicious because it may show 10 to 20 upvotes in a row. Fortunately, at times, I have plenty of time to read everything written here.

Comment: What happened? Can moderators check the details? I mean if they can find out the IPs of the downvoters?

Comment: @kitty The serial downvoting was all reversed automatically.  You can see this for yourself on [Rathony's reputation page](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/24743/rathony?tab=reputation), where it says [voting corrected](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8y5n.png).  If you click on that portion, it leads to a help page describing [serial voting reversal](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed).  Also, since it happened at 3:00 AM, we can tell it was the automatic script that reversed it.

Comment: @kitty Regular users like us can't tell who did the serial downvoting, but moderators can.  They can take additional action if they feel it's warranted, for example sending a moderator message or suspending the downvoter.  Since I'm a regular user on ELL, I have no idea whether or not they've done so, and the moderators aren't likely to tell us; that information is generally kept private.  (Doing otherwise would publicly shame the serial voter, and public shaming isn't particularly productive as a behavior.)

Answer (score 10):

In the case of serial downvoting (one downvoter who downvotes the same account over and over again), as was said in the other answer, those are usually detected by a script and eventually reversed. Expect such downvotes to be removed and the reputation to be restored.

However, in this case, I wonder if something else might have happened as well. The O.P. was serving a suspension for one week. During that week, their reputation was temporarily set to 1. It's quite possible that, during that week, a few downvotes accumulated on various questions, cast by various members. Then, once the suspension was complete and the reputation restored, those accumulated votes may have been processed by the system, leading to what looked like a rash of downvotes all in one minute, but were in fact an accumulation of downvotes over the course of a week.

That being said, at least *some* of the downvotes appear to have been reversed already, since at least [one of the answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74031/a-go-hard-and-fast-to-make-it-count-expression/74032#74032) in the screenshot currently has 0 downvotes.

---

My bottom line recommendations to **anyone** who sees this kind of anomaly in their reputation:

1. Don't panic. If the downvotes are cast out of spite, the system usually catches that, and the problem takes care of itself in due time, thanks to an automated script.
2. Take each downvote with a calm and open mind. Don't assume every downvote is cast because someone is targeting you. Look at each answer and see if there isn't any room for improvement.
3. Remember that downvotes (and upvotes) are a valuable part of the Stack Exchange system. They allow the community to see which answers are deemed as valuable and useful, and which are not. (Imagine how much less useful and interesting this site would be if every answer to every question had no feedback, and was presented on a level footing with all the other answers!)
4. Even though it can be frustrating to get an unexplained downvote, don't pitch a fit when you get one. Remember that just one upvote can offset five downvotes. Also, if someone downvotes your answer, you may have lost two rep points, but they also lost one. The system may not be perfect, but, overall, it's well-designed, and the Stack Exchange has thrived under it.

Answer (score 6):

Not everything deserves a meta post.

There's a [script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting) at place that reverses this bizarre trend of voting. C'est la vie.

Highly related posts on meta, which suddenly make me tired:

[Serial downvoting with pauses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268987/serial-downvoting-with-pauses?s=3|2.9210)

[Serial downvoting not reversed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173330/serial-downvoting-not-reversed?s=4|2.7906)

[serial downvoting not reverted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231553/serial-downvoting-not-reverted?s=6|2.6594)

[Consistent serial downvoting now avoiding detection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130844/consistent-serial-downvoting-now-avoiding-detection?s=7|2.5947)

[Serial Downvoting Reversed with +4 bonus point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137212/serial-downvoting-reversed-with-4-bonus-point?s=9|2.3875)

[Serial downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265985/serial-downvoting?s=10|2.3467)

[Serial downvoting -- is it detected, and what is the threshold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108029/serial-downvoting-is-it-detected-and-what-is-the-threshold?s=11|2.2749)

[Is serial downvoting automatically detected across multiple SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207794/is-serial-downvoting-automatically-detected-across-multiple-se-sites?s=18|2.0320)

And on and on and on. Gee. You can find way more by doing [this search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=serial+downvoting) or [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=serial+downvoting), if you're interested.

Comment: C'est la vie indeed. What are you going to do about the downvoter?

Comment: There's nothing I can do. I'm not a moderator and I don't know who the downvoter is. Possibly, all they'll receive this time is a warning. There is a  danger of suspension if they continue with their behavior. As instructed in that post, you don't need to do anything, just flag for mod attention **after 36 hours** if they weren't reversed. Note that the script runs everyday at 3am UTC.